# My ajax does not working

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

This is may view page:

```
<form method="post" action="" id="saveform" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label>Select Type of Industry</label>
          <select class="form-control" name="industry" id="industry">

            <option value="Advertising">Advertising</option>
            <option value="Aerospace/Defense">Aerospace/Defense</option>
            <option value="air Transport">Air Transport</option>
            <option value="Apparel">Apparel</option>
</form>
```

This is my script but this is not working how to show my data through the controller what is the coding of controller I don't understand:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    $("#saveBtn").click(function(){
      //alert("hjjgjgjhg");
      var industry= $("#industry").val();
      alert(industry);
     $.ajax({
      type:"post",
      data:{"industry": industry},
      url:"<?php echo base_url()?>dive/dive",
      statusCode:{
        200:function(response){
          var data= JSON.parse(response);
          console.log(response);
        }
      }
     });
      });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Is your title some kind of joke?

Comment: which is exactly the error?

Comment: In your provided HTML their no button , select tag is not close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make sure your `controller` and functions are correct 
In browser Network Element You can Trace The Stats Of Ajax
Just Put a `print_r($_POST);` In your controller `dive` with function `dive` And Make Sure you Are Posting Correct Controller.

Just make sure your `controller` and functions are correct 
In browser Network Element You can Trace The Stats Of Ajax
Just Put a `print_r($_POST);` In your controller `dive` with function `dive` And Make Sure you Are Posting Correct Controller. Just make sure your `controller` and functions are correct 
In browser Network Element You can Trace The Stats Of Ajax
Just Put a `print_r($_POST);` In your controller `dive` with function `dive` And Make Sure you Are Posting Correct Controller. Just make sure your `controller` and functions are correct 
In browser Network Element You can Trace The Stats Of Ajax
Just Put a `print_r($_POST);` In your controller `dive` with function `dive` And Make Sure you Are Posting Correct Controller.